# Delete from end of list LinkedList on c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing a method to delete from the end of my linked list. The program crashes when the method is invoked.

```c++
//RemoveBack Method

bool LinkedList::removeBack()
{
  if(isEmpty())
  {
    return(false);
  }
  else 
  {
    Node* temp = m_front;

    while(temp->getNext()!=nullptr)
    {
      temp=temp->getNext();
    }

    delete temp;

    temp=nullptr;
    m_size--;

    return(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You should probably check whether `m_front` is not `nullptr` when you access it inside your function.

Comment: you may also be leaving a dangling pointer - you need to set next on the element before the last one to nullptr also.

Comment: check if m_front == nullptr and, more important issue: "delete temp" is ALWAYS used on nullptr (see the while-loop condition). And yes, learn how to debug your code.